# How to get the data from Jquery.get to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, parameter-passing

I want to load a data that I got from Jquery.get into the variable in another function. The way I have tried is

```
function setPolicy(){
jQuery.get('/webapp/myProject/getPolicy', function(policy) {
    console.log(policy + " Policy"); //Just for Observation
}); }
```

and I want to load the data which is now stored in the Parameter Name "policy" into another variable in another function like the following

```
function loadAPI() {
var policy = setPolicy();
console.log("The policy is " + policy);
```

The result Shows in the console is just

> The policy is

which mean the variable policy is not receive the data from the function.

What I would like to ask is How can I load the data from function "setPolicy" into the variable Name "policy" in another function calls "loadAPI" as a string? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the `console.log(policy + " Policy");` output the policy data sent to the $.get callback?

Comment: simple answer, you can't do it like that

Comment: @MarkErasmus the console Shows the policy that I got from the URL correctly but I can't assign it to the variable in another function.

Comment: The $.get is an asynchronous operation, so the line `console.log("The policy is " + policy);` is executing before the callback is executed, hence the policy is null.

Comment: But the policy of function setPolicy() shows in the console is correct while the policy in loadAPI() function is null. Even I return the policy after the $.get execution but seem like it is not received by variable policy in loadAPI() function. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the fetched value. Try to add this stmt in your code -

```
$.get('URL', function(data) {
$('.result').html(data);
return data;
});
```

Comment: It is not work. The Parameter "data" received a correct data from URL and the value when it return still correct but the variable in another function still undefined

Comment: Strange.! May be variable policy is declared somewhere else also in code ? OR instead of calling func, directly write down your code can help?

Comment: The variable policy is not declared in anywhere. I still able to received the policy from Server side and print out in the console just within the function that execute the URL. I tried to pass it to another function by your Suggestion but it is not work. I also tried to write down the code to the variable but I think it is not good to do so. What I have tried is something like 'var policy = jQuery.get('URL', function(data))'. and it is work...but weird coding in my opinion. I think we should be able to call it from another function. Due to my experience on JavaScript, I do not know how...